# LED Light reflection

Tags: led

I have 20 LEDs on  my board. Due to current limitation, I can not increase LED current after certain point and I need more light illumination or reflection. 
Can PCB with white colour help here rather than usual green PCB colour. I am using white colour LED.

Also is there any other way to achieve reflection from PCB ? (use of optics doesn't fit in my application)

Comment: see if you can specify more efficient LEDs.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I didn't get you. you mean to say use more efficient LEDs ?

Comment: see if you can find LEDs that deliver more lumens per watt. If a tighter beam angle is permissible, then LEDs that emit a tight beam produce a brighter beam than ones that spread their light over a wide angle. The board colour will have little to do with the light going forwards, if the LEDs are already sending all their light forwards. As Jacob's answer asks, are you current limtied, or power limited. If current, then a series connection will get you more power for the same current. If power limited, then it won't help.

Comment: Are these indicators that need to be individually controlled? Or are they ganged together for illumination?

Comment: @harper, All together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the physical layout and orientation of the LEDs on your PCB, changing it to a white one can improve the light output slightly. At least it will help you maintain a more accurate color of the light (especially if you are aiming for white light?)

Are your LEDs connected in series or parallel? If you can connect them in series and supply a higher voltage, you can get a higher power output for a given current.